# Trouble setting up MAMP with AMFPHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, amfphp

I am a pretty decent actionscript 3 developer. I am now trying to get into using php so that my flash games can have user accounts, save user data, etc.

I have been following the instructions of many tutorials, but for some reason it is not connecting. Here is what I have done:

1. Downloaded MAMP, installed it. I can start the servers. It gives me green lights and brings me to the MAMP welcome page. All seems good there...
2. Downloaded AMFPHP, extracted it, and put it in the folder Applications/MAMP/htdocs
3. Enter into browser this -->   `http://localhost/amfphp/gateway/php`

   which results in 404 Not Found page.

I had been using a tutorial that was 3 years old, and it said that I should change the production server constant in the gateway.php file to false since I am trying to connect locally at the moment. The problem is, though, that *there is no gateway.php* file here.

I am pretty sure I need to change something in some php file itself, but I have no idea how to find it or what I am even looking for. I am an actionscript 3 developer, and in order to learn php I need to have it set up so I can start using it! If anyone has done this already and can see where I am going wrong, help is much appreciated! Thanks, Jim

Note: there is a Gateway.php file, but it looks nothing like the one in the tutorial, and there is no production server constant to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at old tutorials for v1.9 or earlier. In v2.x it's UnzippedFolder/Amphp/, or UnzippedFolder/Amphp/index.php.

Comment: Not sure what you mean my "it". is there an amfphp 2 tutorial somewhere?